# Real life applications for the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, applications

I was just wondering what were the main/important uses of the Fibonacci sequence as well as any other generalized Fibonacci sequences in real life applications.

Comment: Try thinking about a snail shell...

Comment: @simplest_mathematics: what ??

Comment: AFAIK, many shelled animal's shells follow a fibbonachi sequence.Search [online:](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fibonacci+shell+drawing)

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html), entitled "15 Uncanny Examples of the Golden Ratio in Nature"

Comment: And of course you first tried [the obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#In_nature) and the links therein?

Comment: @simplest_mathematics: the second entry in your link precisely states that thoses shells do *not* obey a Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Sorry, @YvesDaoust, wrong link ; search golden spiral instead. I think it was something like that.                                                      ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @simplest_mathematics: you'd better read the link by Did.

Comment: @YveDaoust, I have read it.

Comment: And I agree with it...

Comment: @simplest_mathematics: glad to know that we both agree that golden spirals in shells is pure folklore, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the Fibonacci sequence have no particular "uses" in real life and they are more relevant in the frame of certain mathematical models.

A particular application I think of is when you know that a function has a single maximum in a given interval. Then it is proven that the optimal sequence of function evaluations to narrow down the maximum is obtained with intervals having a length proportional to the terms of Fibonacci.

But I wouldn't call that real life.

Comment: See http://www.teamnotus.com/ and download "Final Report Senior Design I". It's about a turbine called Liam F1 Urban Wind Turbine.

Comment: @cgiovanardi: I wonder if the choice of the golden section has any functional justification, other than propagating the folklore.

Comment: @cgiovanardi: where the hell do you see a connection to Fibonacci in these spirals ?

Answer (score 1):

In computer science, there is a data structure called a [Fibonacci Heap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) that works by storing items in a collection of heaps with degrees that are ascending Fibonacci numbers. Fibonacci heaps have significantly better performance in certain tasks than other similar data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways you can climb stairs from 0 to stair N is a fibonacci sequence provided you can climb 1 or 2 stairs at one time. Not real life really but if you want to know :D